# Add keywords to a highlight group

Tags: syntax-highlighting, syntax, keyword

`Todo` highlight group currently highlights `TODO` and `FIXME` keywords. What do I do to add `NOTE`, and possibley more keywords, to this existing highlight group, for all file types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following to your .vimrc:

```
fun! SetMyTodos()
    syn match myTodos /\%(HABA:\)\|\%(NOTE:\)/
    hi link myTodos Todo
endfu
autocmd bufenter * :call SetMyTodos()
autocmd filetype * :call SetMyTodos()
```

Restart. Then everytime you will set filetype (usually when you edit a file) or when you enter a buffer (:e newfile) it will add a `myTodos` syntax that is highlighted as a `Todo`.

It is just an example, though :)

[image]

Comment: What's the use of `%`?

Comment: do not create matched groups `:h /\%(`

Comment: You can also use syn keyword of course if you need just a words to be highlighted: `syn keyword myTodos MYXXX OTHERXXX ANOTHER`

Comment: Does this highlight the keywords inside comments? I don't think so.

Comment: It doesn't indeed.

Answer (score 15):

The highlight group `Todo` just defines how a "todo" should be highlighted. What is actually highlighted by `Todo` is defined by the syntax. For the C language, the expression is:

```
syn keyword     cTodo           contained TODO FIXME XXX
```

This defines the syntax group `cTodo`, that contains the named keywords. This syntax group is later linked to highlight group `Todo` with the following:

```
hi def link cTodo       Todo
```

If you want to add an additional keyword to the `cTodo` syntax group, you should create the file `~/.vim/after/syntax/c.vim` (`~/vimfiles/after/syntax/c.vim` on Windows) with the following content:

```
" Add NOTE as todo keyword
syntax keyword cTodo contained NOTE
```

So this definition is syntax-specific. For python it would be `pythonTodo` and the file would be `~.vim/after/syntax/python.vim`.

See `:help :syn-keyword` and `:help :syn-contained`.

---

**Add-on:** How do I delete a keyword from am syntax keyword group?

AFAIK, there is no way to do that directly. You have to clear the entire group and rebuild it. Like:

```
syntax clear cTodo
syntax keyword cTodo contained TODO FIXME NOTE
```

---

**Add-on:** How do I know how the "todo" syntax group is named for a given language?

Most likely it is `<file-type>Todo`. To be sure, create a file of this language and add a "todo" comment. Move the cursor to the highlighted word and execute:

```
echo synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 1), "name")
```

If you need to do that more than once, you might want to define a new command in Vim by adding the following to your `vimrc`:

```
" Show name of syntax element below cursor
command! SynName  echo synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 1), "name")
```

---

**Update:** How to add "todo" keywords for all file types?

This is more complicated. Now you need a autocmd and a function to find the
correct syntax groups and extend them.

Why is it important to add the new keywords to the existing definitions? Well, Vim syntax knows `contained` and `contains=...`. The "todo" syntax group is defined as `contained`, that means, that it is only highlighted, when is is contained in another syntax group. On the other hand the syntax group(s) for comments is defined with `contains=xxxTodo`, so "todos" are highlighted within comments.

Here you go:

```
function! UpdateTodoKeywords(...)
    let newKeywords = join(a:000, " ")
    let synTodo = map(filter(split(execute("syntax list"), '\n') , { i,v -> match(v, '^\w*Todo\>') == 0}), {i,v -> substitute(v, ' .*$', '', '')})
    for synGrp in synTodo
        execute "syntax keyword " . synGrp . " contained " . newKeywords
    endfor
endfunction

augroup now
    autocmd!
    autocmd Syntax * call UpdateTodoKeywords("NOTE", "NOTES")
augroup END
```

The function `UpdateTodoKeywords` is called whenever a syntax is loaded and adds the given keywords to all
"todo" syntax groups. You can add multiple names to the call to `UpdateTodoKeywords`, as mutch as you want (but at least one).

Note that there are syntax definitions, that contain multiple definitions for "todo". E.g. 
for Vim script files also python syntax is loaded, so it has `vimTodo` and `pythonTodo`.

The function is strait forward, except for the line `let synTodo = map(...`. Here is what that line does:

1. It lists all syntax items (`execute("syntax list")`)
2. Splits it into a list of lines (`split(..., '\n')`)
3. Filters it to only contain lines with syntax group name that ends with `Todo` (`filter(..., { i,v -> match(v, '^\w*Todo\>') == 0})`)
4. Removes everything after syntax group name (`map(..., {i,v -> substitute(v, ' .*$', '', '')})`)

So the result of this is a list of syntax group names that end with `Todo`.

Then for every syntax group name it adds the given keywords.

PS: This even works, if the "todo" syntax group is initially defined as `syn-match`.

---

**Finally:** The "brute force attempt":

You could use the following:

```
autocmd Syntax * syntax keyword myTodo NOTE NOTES containedin=ALL | highlight def link myTodo TODO
```

This defines a new syntax group `myTodo` that will be contained in every existing syntax group. So it will highlight "NOTE" and "NOTES" everywhere. In comments, in strings or if you use it as a variable name.

Comment: What if I want to add `NOTE` to all of the <filetype>Todo? I mean do I have to add all the filetypes by myself? And if so, then I think it would be simpler to define my own `syn keyword`, how do I do that (also mention location of the file in this case)?

Comment: match, matchadd() wouldn't highlight the pattern for all windows, would it? Then I guess, `match` is not the answer.

Comment: @klaus See my update.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is really definitive, I learnt a lot. Sadly I've already selected the correct answer. Gave an upvote though.